# how to get woocommerce shipping class price/cost using shipping class id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get shipping class cost assigned to products.

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ($items as $item) {
$product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);
$shipping_class_id = $product->get_shipping_class_id();
}
```

i don't know how to get the cost of the shipping class based on its id can anyone help me?

Comment: **This is not possible** as Shipping classes are independent from Shipping Zones and Methods, meaning that a shipping class cost depends on the customer location and on the selected method.

Comment: any way to access the flat rate shipping that has shipping class inside?

Comment: i am seeing ``wp_options`` table that has option name ``woocommerce_flat_rate_1_settings`` with value  flat rate and shipping class info as serialized object/array. anyway to access this a in plugin without hard coding the option name?

Comment: The option_name is derivable from `'woocommerce_' . $shipping_method->method_id . '_' . $shipping_method->instance_id . '_settings'`, if that's any use.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 foreach ($order->get_items('shipping') as $item_id => $shipping) 
            {   
                $method_id = $shipping->get_method_id();
                $name      = $shipping->get_name();
                $total     = $shipping->get_total();
            }
```